# Uncaught WebDriverError: null

Tags: node.js, selenium, electron

I'm running Selenium (with PhantomJS) within an Electron app (**don't ask why**). Because I have to package the app together, I'm using the [`selenium-standalone`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-standalone) library to run Selenium. As far as I know, the server is starting up correctly, and my application is able to call it.

But when I try to create a new session/navigate to a page, I get

```
Uncaught WebDriverError: null
```

The problem is occuring on any page I visit with selenium. After digging a little deeper I found that the WebDriver session wasn't being created correctly. Here is my stack trace:

```
WebDriverError: null
    at WebDriverError (/some/path/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/some/path/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:639:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/some/path/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:538:13)
    at client_.send.then.response (/some/path/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:472:11)
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/some/path/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (/some/path/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/some/path/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
    at asyncRun (/some/path/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2820:25)
    at /some/path/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/some/path/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:349:29)
```

Here is the faulty code:

```
driver = new selenium.Builder()
    .withCapabilities(selenium.Capabilities.phantomjs())
    .build();
```

I'm running Electron 1.3.1 on Mac OS X El Capitan, if that helps.

Has anyone had this issue before? The problem seems to originate from the Java selenium server, but I'm not sure what's going on in the driver that causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading phantomjs will help to fix this issue.
Try following steps.

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
sudo npm -g install phantomjs-prebuilt
```